Can we change the collapse arrow for header of blender panel?

I'm working on customizing the UI of Blender (version 4.2.0) and need to modify the default collapse arrow icon in a custom panel. By default, Blender uses its own collapse arrow. I want to replace this default collapse arrow with a custom icon and have it display TRIA_RIGHT when the panel is collapsed and TRIA_DOWN when it is expanded.
So the final panel should look someting like this
enter image description here
import bpy
from bpy.props import BoolProperty

class LayoutDemoPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Layout Panel Demo"
    bl_idname = "SCENE_PT_layout_panel"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "scene"
    bl_options = {'HIDE_HEADER'}

    def draw_header(self, context):
        self.layout.label(text="", icon="TRIA_RIGHT")


    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        scene = context.scene

        layout.label(text="Basic Panels")

        header, panel = layout.panel("my_panel_id", default_closed=True)
        header.label(text="Hello World")
        print(header.icon)
        if panel:
            panel.label(text="Success")

        header, panel = layout.panel_prop(scene, "show_demo_panel")
        
        # header.icon()
        if panel:
            header.label(text="My Panel", icon="TRIA_DOWN")
            panel.prop(scene, "frame_start")
            panel.prop(scene, "frame_end")
        else: header.label(text="My Panel", icon="TRIA_RIGHT")

        layout.label(text="Customized headers")

        # Add a checkbox to the Panel header. text must be None for this panel
        header, panel = layout.panel("my_panel_id-2", default_closed=True)
        header.prop(scene, "use_checkmark", text="") # text must be empty for the checkbox
        header.label(text="Checkmark at beginning")
        if panel:
            panel.label(text="Success")

        header, panel = layout.panel("my_panel_id-3", default_closed=True)
        header.label(text="Buttons at the end")
        header.operator("mesh.primitive_cube_add", text="", icon='EXPORT')
        header.operator("mesh.primitive_cube_add", text="", icon='X')
        if panel:
            panel.label(text="Success")

        header, panel = layout.panel("my_panel_id-4", default_closed=True)
        header.prop(scene, "use_checkmark2", text="")
        header.label(text="Both")
        header.operator("mesh.primitive_cube_add", text="", icon='EXPORT')
        header.operator("mesh.primitive_cube_add", text="", icon='X')
        if panel:
            panel.label(text="Success")

bpy.utils.register_class(LayoutDemoPanel)
bpy.types.Scene.show_demo_panel = BoolProperty(default=False)
bpy.types.Scene.use_checkmark = BoolProperty(default=False)
bpy.types.Scene.use_checkmark2 = BoolProperty(default=False)

